# Multi-label text classification/regression using torchtext

Tags: nlp, pytorch, regression, text-classification, torchtext

I would like to use torchtext to implement a Transformer-based neural network for a multi-label classification task, where the labels are a list of values.

This is how my training data looks like:

```
0: {"sentence": ['word_1', 'word_2', 'word_3', 'word_4', 'word_5', 'word_6'], 
    "labels": [('word_2', [<DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>]), 
        ('word_3', [<DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>]),
        ('word_6', [<DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>])]} 

1: {"sentence": ['word_1', 'word_2', 'word_3', 'word_4'], 
    "labels": [('word_4', [<DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>])}
```

The main characteristics of the dataset are:

- the sentences have different lengths
- the number of target words in labels is not the same
- the target words are different in each training instance
- each target word is accompanied by a list of decimal values (fixed length, e.g. 4)

The input to the system is a tokenized sentence, and the output should be a multi-output regression, e.g. `[<DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>]`.

Since I am new to torchtext, and I didn't found datasets having such characteristics on the web, I need some help/ideas/opinions on how to prepare this kind of data to feed it to a transformer using torchtext. I would like to know (1) if it is feasible to implement this task with torchtext, and (2) how should I define the `labels` for the `fields`?

Have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As posed, this question is not a particularly good fit for this site. If you have an attempt to implement your text classification model using torchtext and find it doesn't work, you can ask us how to debug your code.

Comment: I'll add that the framing of this problem is somewhat unusual insomuch as sequence tagging problems typically asign _one label_ to _each token_ (O being the default label). It doesn't seem impossible to extend sequence tagging approaches to work with your framing, though.

Comment: Make sure, whatever tutorial/guide you are working off of, you are using [the most recent release of torchtext](https://github.com/pytorch/text). It's harder to find tutorials, but it's worth it to be working with the newest features.